# python - replacing a slice from string

Tags: python

In a string

```
s = 'I am a damn string'
```

If I wish to remove the characters from index from 7 to 10, (i.e. to remove a slice and keep the remainder string).

I know, I can do like --

```
newString = s[:6] + s[11:]
```

Is there any better (pythonic) way?
Thanks.

Comment: `newString = s[:6] + s[11:]  ` is the most simple and pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: If your intention is to remove sub string, you can use `.replace` like `newString = s.replace('damn', '')`.

Comment: 'damn' is not fixed. Tomorrow it may be 'xxxx'. Why to hard-code!

Comment: @RafaelC and it's also the fastest if there are only 2 strings to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternativ could be the join method. Especially if you have more than one slice, e.g.

```
newString = ''.join([s[:6], s[8:12], s[16:]])
```